# Font kerning breaks with absolute div inbetween

Tags: html, css, kerning

I have the following HTML with `.popup` having `absolute` positioning:

```
<span class="has-popup">載っ<div class="popup">Distance between っ and て changed :(</div>てる</span>
```

The popup visibility is toggled between `none` and `block` by hovering events. With the div invisible the kerning works as expected and the distance between っ and て stays small. With the div visible however the distance between the characters increases (seemingly the kerning is disabled).

[image: Example]

Is there a reliable way to enable kerning across an embedded div like this?

The behaviour also seems to differ between browsers. The above described effect happens on Firefox but on Chromium the kerning seems to work as expected in both cases. Am I dealing with a browser bug here or is the intended behaviour undefined?

I set up a fiddle to test this: https://jsfiddle.net/q9wkcLbr/

Comment: I am not seeing the problem on either Firefox or Edge/Chrome on Windows10. What system are you using that shows the problem?

Comment: The issue is present with Firefox 89.0.2 (64-bit) on Manjaro Linux 21.0.7